# How to Remove Numbers in Steps in PrimeNG?

Tags: angular8, primeng

I am using PrimeNG Steps. How to remove the numbers in steps?

I tried using the Default CSS Property.

Answer (score 0):

component has no option for this ,but you can use **css** to hide the innerHtml by after pseudo-element

style.scss (global style)

```css
p-steps{
  .ui-steps-number { 
    overflow: hidden
  }

.ui-steps-number::after {
    content: '';
    background: currentColor;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

 .ui-steps .ui-steps-item.ui-state-highlight .ui-steps-number {
    color: #007ad9 !important;
}

  .ui-steps .ui-steps-item .ui-steps-number {
    color: #ccc !important;
}
}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-steps)

the style above will change the style for all p-steps components but you can use custom `styleClass` like this

*template*

```html
<p-steps styleClass="dot-theme" [model]="items" 
     [(activeIndex)]="activeIndex" [readonly]="false">
</p-steps>
```

style.scss

```css
.dot-theme {
  .ui-steps-number { 
    overflow: hidden
  }

.ui-steps-number::after {
    content: '';
    background: currentColor ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.ui-state-highlight .ui-steps-number {
    color: #007ad9 !important;
}

   .ui-steps-number {
    color: #ccc !important;
}
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-steps-9wixhn)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide the text setting it's colour to transparent:

```
.p-steps .p-steps-item .p-menuitem-link .p-steps-number {
  color: transparent;
}
```